# "How to convert a Duration(ex. 2h 50m, 8h 35m) an object column in a dataframe into a datetime column with only minutes?"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column named Duration in my data frame.

The duration in the column is in the format `2h 50m, 8h 35m, 19h and so on`.

This column type is an `'object'`.

How to convert the whole column to just minutes like 2h 50m = 170m, 8h 35m = 515m?

I tried using

```py
df['Col_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col_name'])
```

Comment: what's the result when you do `type( df.loc[0,'Col_name'] )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for numeric values, multiple hours by `60`, sum together by [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html), convert to integers, strings and last add `m`:

```
h = df['Col_name'].str.extract('(\d+)h', expand=False).astype(float) * 60
m = df['Col_name'].str.extract('(\d+)m', expand=False).astype(float)

df['new'] = h.add(m, fill_value=0).astype(int).astype(str) + 'm'
```

Another solution, thanks @anky_91:

```
df['new1'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['Col_name']).dt.seconds // 60).astype(str) + 'm'
print (df)

  Col_name    new   new1
0   2h 50m   170m   170m
1   8h 35m   515m   515m
2      19h  1140m  1140m
```

But if need processing later this data by datetimelike functions is possible convert it to timedeltas:

```
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Col_name'])
print (df)
  Col_name    new   new1 timedelta
0   2h 50m   170m   170m  02:50:00
1   8h 35m   515m   515m  08:35:00
2      19h  1140m  1140m  19:00:00
```